# Microsoft Remote Desktop Server for OS X

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

Is there any solution that would allow ke to run a Terminal Services or RDP server on my Mac?

I'd like to be able to access my Mac via Microsoft's Remote Desktop application
I am aware of Screen Sharing fir OS X

Also, if there is no specific way to do this, is there any way to use the linux xrdp package on OS X?

Answer (score 1):

On [this site](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/remote-access-apple-mac-os-x-via-windows/2/) are listed 5 possible programs to do this, as native this isn't possible.

Explained are:

1. TeamViewer
2. LogMeIn (free)
3. Real VNC
4. Vine Server
5. Remote Management

Note, LogMeIn does not have a free version anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is now iRAPP and iRAPP Terminal Server from coderebel.com -

http://www.coderebel.com/products/irapp

http://www.coderebel.com/products/irapp-terminal-server